# Создание обработчика по нажатию на inline кнопки и получение текста этой кнопки

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Создаю телеграм бота на основе telebot
У меня динамически создаются кнопки в массиве

```
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard.row_width = 2
for i in range(0, len(adress)):
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(adress[i].text, callback_data=adress[i].text))
bot.send_message(cid, 'Выберите адрес парковки', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Как мне отследить нажатие одной из кнопок и получить из неё текст? У всех кнопок разный callback_data

Если бы я знал их callback_date, то я бы сделал так:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def ans(c):
    cid = c.message.chat.id
    if c.data == "callback_data":
```

Но как это сделать в моём случае если callback_data формируется динамически?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard.row_width = 2
for i in range(0, len(adress)):
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(adress[i].text, callback_data=f"address_{adress[i].text}"))
bot.send_message(cid, 'Выберите адрес парковки', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Хэндлер:

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(lambda query: query.data.startswith("address_"))
def ans(query):
    chat_id = query.message.chat.id
    address = query.data.split("_")[1] # адрес, с которым можно работать
```

Comment: `chat_id = query.message.chat.id
    print(chat_id)
    address = query.data.split("_")[0] # адрес, с которым можно работать
    print(address)`
Получаю `228695396` и `address`
Обработчик получилось сделать. Как теперь получить текст кнопки?

Comment: @Иван к сожалению, текст кнопки никак не получить из CallbackQuery

Comment: А как тогда получить callback_data? Я же в неё вставил то же самое, что и в текст кнопки

Comment: @Иван так я же Вам указал, в переменной address = query.data.split("_")[0] находится ваш адрес, работайте с ней

Comment: Нет, в ней находиться `address`, а должно быть https://imgur.com/a/4eIqTCG

Comment: Возможно как-то нужно ещё обрабатывать. Я вывожу `print(address)` и получаю `address`, а должен `ул. Ратная, 27`

Comment: @Иван ой, обновил код, должно быть так: `address = query.data.split("_")[1] # адрес, с которым можно работать`

Answer (score 2):

В `callback_data` указывайте адрес `callback_data=f"address_{adress[i].text}"`

Обработчик

`@bot.callback_query_handler(lambda query: query.data.startswith("address_")) def ans(query): str = query.data res_str = str.replace('address_', '')`

В переменной `res_str` будет `callback_data` вашей кнопки